# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str Using Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am still learning stuff through python and would like your help.

```json
{
  "context": {
    "authnAttemptId": "14fee7f5-2f81-448c-a0ca-41558eb68b8f",
    "messageId": "e1d8e981-5b71-4434-b92e-182f1706dd95",
    "inResponseTo": "42dd9ss"
  },
  "credentialValidationResults": [
    {
      "methodId": "APPROVE",
      "methodResponseCode": "IN_PROCESS",
      "methodReasonCode": "VERIFICATION_PENDING:",
      "authnAttributes": []
    }
  ],
  "attemptResponseCode": "CHALLENGE",
  "attemptReasonCode": "METHOD_VERIFY_IN_PROCESS",
  "challengeMethods": {
    "challenges": [
      {
        "methodSetId": "850e5638-54c5-4429-9fa8-e48da2594736",
        "requiredMethods": [
          {
            "methodId": "APPROVE",
            "displayName": "Approve",
            "priority": 1,
            "versions": [
              {
                "versionId": "1.0.0",
                "methodAttributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "deviceName",
                    "value": "DESKTOP-P1S563M",
                    "dataType": "STRING"
                  }
                ],
                "valueRequired": false,
                "referenceId": "14fee7f5-2f81-448c-a0ca-41558eb68b8f:P6JQ",
                "prompt": {
                  "promptResourceId": "IA.Resource.Prompt.Approve",
                  "defaultText": "Initiate Approve? ",
                  "formatRegex": null,
                  "defaultValue": null,
                  "valueBeingDefined": false,
                  "sensitive": true,
                  "minLength": null,
                  "maxLength": null,
                  "promptArgs": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "methodSetId": "3dd02306-212e-47e2-b14f-cf0bb6f87e4d",
        "requiredMethods": [
          {
            "methodId": "FINGERPRINT",
            "displayName": "Device Biometrics",
            "priority": 50,
            "versions": [
              {
                "versionId": "1.0.0",
                "methodAttributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "deviceName",
                    "value": "DESKTOP-P1S563M",
                    "dataType": "STRING"
                  }
                ],
                "valueRequired": false,
                "referenceId": null,
                "prompt": {
                  "promptResourceId": "IA.Resource.Prompt.Fingerprint",
                  "defaultText": "Initiate Fingerprint? ",
                  "formatRegex": null,
                  "defaultValue": null,
                  "valueBeingDefined": false,
                  "sensitive": true,
                  "minLength": null,
                  "maxLength": null,
                  "promptArgs": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "methodSetId": "649243db-928e-42ac-b009-42ca278c0a75",
        "requiredMethods": [
          {
            "methodId": "FIDOTOKEN_INITIALIZE_CHALLENGE",
            "displayName": "FIDO Challenge",
            "priority": 50,
            "versions": [
              {
                "versionId": "1.0.0",
                "methodAttributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "METHOD_NOT_APPLICABLE",
                    "value": "DEVICE_NOT_CAPABLE",
                    "dataType": "STRING"
                  }
                ],
                "valueRequired": false,
                "referenceId": null,
                "prompt": {
                  "promptResourceId": "IA.Resource.Prompt.Fido_Initialize_Challenge",
                  "defaultText": "Start FIDO Authentication? ",
                  "formatRegex": null,
                  "defaultValue": null,
                  "valueBeingDefined": false,
                  "sensitive": true,
                  "minLength": null,
                  "maxLength": null,
                  "promptArgs": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "methodSetId": "d896e4e8-49ef-48fd-a232-8a3c3d7e97b0",
        "requiredMethods": [
          {
            "methodId": "TOKEN",
            "displayName": "Authenticate Tokencode",
            "priority": 50,
            "versions": [
              {
                "versionId": "1.0.0",
                "methodAttributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "deviceName",
                    "value": "DESKTOP-P1S563M",
                    "dataType": "STRING"
                  }
                ],
                "valueRequired": true,
                "referenceId": null,
                "prompt": {
                  "promptResourceId": "IA.Resource.Prompt.Token",
                  "defaultText": "Enter Tokencode: ",
                  "formatRegex": null,
                  "defaultValue": null,
                  "valueBeingDefined": false,
                  "sensitive": true,
                  "minLength": null,
                  "maxLength": null,
                  "promptArgs": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "methodSetId": "5324cd43-62eb-4b55-acdb-93d0079a79a9",
        "requiredMethods": [
          {
            "methodId": "EMERGENCY_TOKENCODE",
            "displayName": "Emergency Tokencode",
            "priority": 100,
            "versions": [
              {
                "versionId": "1.0.0",
                "methodAttributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "METHOD_NOT_APPLICABLE",
                    "value": "METHOD_NOT_ENROLLED",
                    "dataType": "STRING"
                  }
                ],
                "valueRequired": true,
                "referenceId": null,
                "prompt": {
                  "promptResourceId": "IA.Resource.Prompt.Emergency_Tokencode",
                  "defaultText": "Enter your Emergency Tokencode: ",
                  "formatRegex": "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$",
                  "defaultValue": null,
                  "valueBeingDefined": false,
                  "sensitive": true,
                  "minLength": 8,
                  "maxLength": 12,
                  "promptArgs": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "methodSetId": "1e2046ad-1c4e-4045-b30c-d39c1a48db86",
        "requiredMethods": [
          {
            "methodId": "SECURID",
            "displayName": "RSA SecurID",
            "priority": 50,
            "versions": [
              {
                "versionId": "1.0.0",
                "methodAttributes": [],
                "valueRequired": true,
                "referenceId": null,
                "prompt": {
                  "promptResourceId": "IA.Resource.Prompt.SecurId_Passcode",
                  "defaultText": "Enter PASSCODE: ",
                  "formatRegex": null,
                  "defaultValue": null,
                  "valueBeingDefined": false,
                  "sensitive": true,
                  "minLength": null,
                  "maxLength": null,
                  "promptArgs": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So what I am doing is I want to get the value present in this JSON response which is the reference: 14fee7f5-2f81-448c-a0ca-41558eb68b8f:P6JQ

so I am using the following command in python:

```py
result2 = response2.json()
reference_id_approve = result2['challengeMethods']['challenges']['methodSetId']['requiredMethods']['versions']['referenceId']
```

However, I am getting the error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices.

Appreciate your help :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to hear. There is a list somewhere and you are using a string as an index. But you can only use integers (or slices) as index for lists.

Comment: I am trying to put the value of the reference id into a variable so I can use it later on in the next step.

Comment: Okay. Then you need to fix the code where you are using a string as a list index (by using an integer as index instead).

Comment: If you are unsure where you need to make a change, you need to answer these questions for yourself, until the answer to one of them is "yes": (1) is `result2` a list? (2) is `result2['challengeMethods']` a list? (3) is `result2['challengeMethods']['challenges']` a list? (4) etc.

Comment: `['challengeMethods']['challenges']` is a list

Comment: Basically, don't drill down all at once.  Do it one step-at-a-time until you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If `result` is set to that whole dictionary, the correct path to the value '14fee7f5-2f81-448c-a0ca-41558eb68b8f:P6JQ' is:

```
result["challengeMethods"]["challenges"][0]["requiredMethods"][0]["versions"][0]["referenceId"]
```

When you are addressing to an element of a dictionary (class `dict`), you use a its key, that can be any hashable object (a string (class `str`), for example). When you are addressing to an element of a list (class `list`) you use its index, that is an integer (class `int`). (The index of the first element is 0)

```
`type(d)`-->`dict`
`type(d["challengeMethods"])`-->`dict`
`type(d["challengeMethods"]["challenges"])`-->`list`
`type(d["challengeMethods"]["challenges"][0])`-->`dict`
`type(d["challengeMethods"]["challenges"][0]["requiredMethods"][0]["versions"])`-->`list`
`type(d["challengeMethods"]["challenges"][0]["requiredMethods"][0]["versions"][0]["referenceId"])`-->`str`
```